# Change / Replace complete Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, attributes

I need to add an attribure to this Javascript line in my WordPress site.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.domainname.com/wp-content/plugins/instagram-feed/js/sb-instagram.min.js?ver=1.8.3"></script>
```

Is it possible to create a function, locate this exact line of code and replace it with another one only with an extra attribute in it?

**Edit**

Ok, so it is not possible to change this line after its loaded. Was afraid this was the issue.

I now trying another solution and I think I'm almost there but somehow I cant figure out how to load the script back.

The script I am talking about is registered in the plug-in files (that I dont want to edit).

```
wp_register_script( 'sb_instagram_scripts', plugins_url( '/js/sb-instagram.min.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), SBIVER, true ); //http://www.minifier.org/
```

Now I found a way to dequeue this script so it doesnt get loaded. I'm doing this in my function.php

**Functions.php**

```
    function deque_instagram_javascript(){
    wp_dequeue_script('sb_instagram_scripts');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'deque_instagram_javascript', 100 );
```

Now the Instagram Cookie is not set yet. I'm using Cookiebot and want to give users the option to set this InstaGram cookie. So with this code you can create an if statement to do something when yo accept the marketing cookies. This is in de footer.php

I also created a new variable to register the script again.

**Footer.php**

```
    <?php
$instagram_script_register =  wp_register_script( 'sb_instagram_scripts', plugins_url( '/js/sb-instagram.min.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), SBIVER, true ); //http://www.minifier.org/
        $instagram_script_enq =  wp_enqueue_script( 'sb_instagram_scripts'); //http://www.minifier.org/
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CookiebotCallback_OnAccept() {
            if (Cookiebot.consent.marketing)
            {
                enableInstaMarketing();
            }
        }
            function enableInstaMarketing() {
            var instagram_script_register = "<?php echo $instagram_script_register ?>";
            var instagram_script_enq = "<?php echo $instagram_script_enq ?>";    
            }
    </script>
```

Dequeue is working but I'm not able to get it to load (enqueue) again when accepting the marketing cookies.

Is what I'm trying not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: see if this helps https://wordpress.org/support/topic/load-sb-instagram-script-on-all-pages/

Comment: You cannot find this line until after the line has loaded. Once the line has been read it will execute and then it is too late to change

Comment: Ok, I was allready afraid that was the issue. I have tried to realise it another way. Will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

If this script is added through ``, and you know it's handle, you can do something like this

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'additional_script_attributes', 15, 3);

function additional_script_attributes($tag, $handle, $src)
{
    if ($handle !== 'your_script_handle')
    {
        return $tag;
    }

    return str_replace('\'></script>', '\' async></script>', $tag);
}
```

You can replace `async` with whatever you need. Basically, `$tag` has html code to add this specific script. You can edit it as you want, `str_replace` is but one simple way to do so.